# Play Framework 2.X Models definition in a concurrent application

Tags: java, jpa, orm, playframework-2.0, ebean

Developing a **Play Framework 2.3.X** application here using the **Ebean ORM**.

I just have some doubts that i really want to clarify about best practice when defining my models in order to make them "safe" in a concurrent environment.

All my models as suggested by the documentation are extending the `play.db.ebean.Model` and i have some instances that can be modified by different sources.

For example i have this simple model, a User

```
public class User extends Model {
@Id
public Long id;
public String name;
public String surname;
public String email;
public String password;
public int credits
}
```

that has some credits on his account. He can recharge them and can start and have jobs in background that can consume them. 
I red that when having concurrent access/writes to a model is a wise choice to add a

```
@Version
public Long version
```

field to each instance in order to avoid inconsistent states in the model, and when this happens an `OptimisticLockException` will be thrown.

The question is, is the `@Version` annotation the best solution in a application like mine?

Are out there some best practice that i'm missing and that could be used in order to reduce the chance of getting an `optimisticLockExceptions` and if yes, which ones ??

Let's say the `optimisticLockExceptions` occurs when making an automatic payments by the system, for example after a credit cards payment, is it safe to loop while the transaction does complete successfully, thus by not throwing an `optimisticLockExceptions` ?

Should i add the `@Version` annotation to each model of my application ?

Sorry for being so meticulous but the models layer has to be as much robust as possibile.
Hoping some of you can help me, answering even to some of my questions

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

Optimistic locking works like:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET fields = :new_fields, version = :old_version + 1 WHERE version = :old_version AND id = :id;
```

if nothing updated it means that object changed or deleted since last read, so you need to repeat last transaction.

Optimistic locking is good when you have a lot of reading operations from database and small count of concurrent writing operations. But when you have high concurrent writes on the same entity you will receive a lot of `optimisticLockExceptions` -> you will perform a lot of transaction rollbacks. For example 10 concurrent write operation on the same entity can create up to 45 failed transactions and only 10 successed. Of course in case when you repeat transaction until success. Its potencial vulnerability: some 'hacker' can perform a lot of requests that perform concurrent updates on the same entity. So I suggest to limit repeats to reasonable count.

You need to add `@Version` to all entities that need support of optimistic locking. Of course in case when some entity type will be updated only with another entity that already contains `@Version` you can don't add it, but it can produce errors in future when this behaviour changed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but i didn't understand the last paragraph.
So it's correct to execute transaction until the transaction succeed, but i'm still missing the answer to which are the best practice i can use in order to reduce the chance of getting an optimisticLockException.

Comment: optimisticLockException is ok, its just mean that there was another concurrent update. If you have a lot of optimisticLockException then might it will be better to use pessimistic locking (without @Version) for that entity. There no another way to reduce optimisticLockException count (may be use sharding counter pattern if possible can help, but it  database side).